# Why does server-side Blazor need to download all .NET dlls to the Browser?

Tags: blazor-server-side

In the current version of Server-side Blazor all code runs on the server and the Browser gets updated using SignalR and some kind of JavaScript Proxy that updates the DOM in the Browser whenever the 'shadow-DOM' on the server changes. Then why is the mono.wasm, the client DLL and all dependent .NET DLLs downloaded to the Browser?

These files are loaded into the Browser:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's easily done, but it looks like you've accidentally created a blazor client app. To confirm it, I just created one and got exactly the same files shown as in your screenshot.
I then created a server-side blazor app, and get just these files instead...
(Notice that I don't have blazor.webassembly.js or mono or *.client.dll
But I do have one that says blazor.server.js.

**Files loaded into the browser:**

[image: Files loaded into the browser]

Comment: Indeed I followed the instructions of an older tutorial and selected 'Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted)' and it should have been 'Blazor Server App'. The phrase '(ASP.NET Core hosted)' suggest a server-side solution, but it is not.
Thanks a lot!